# Module attempts to access a secure API

Tags: blackberry, code-signing

I am trying to load my BlackBerry application through the BlackBerry Device Manager. The application loads but when I try to open it I get "Error Starting --- Module attempts to access a secure API". I have successfully signed the app.

This is how I signed the app:
BlackBerry -> Sign -> Install new keys
Right click the project -> BlackBerry -> Sign with Signature tool.
I get a confirmation of "6 files signed successfully". However in my java files, I still see the "yellow mark" next to some lines of code saying "signing required".

When I tried to load the app from Eclipse "Load Project on device" I got the following:

NOTE: I just tried BlackBerry -> Load Project on device and I got the following error:

> C:\Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack6.0.0_6.0.0.43\components\bin\rapc.exe -convertpng -quiet codename=deliverables\Standard\6.0.0\TestBBELMS deliverables\Standard\6.0.0\TestBBELMS.rapc -sourceroot=C:\Users\abc\Documents\workspace\TestBBELMS\src;C:\Users\abc\Documents\workspace\TestBBELMS\res;C:\Users\abc\Documents\workspace\TestBBELMS -import=C:\Eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack6.0.0_6.0.0.43\components\lib\net_rim_api.jar C:\Users\abc\Downloads\Ksoap2LibPrev_and_sample_code\ksoap2-j2me-core-prev-2.1.2.jar C:\Users\abc\Documents\workspace\TestBBELMS\bin\deliverables\Web\6.0.0\TestBBELMS.jad C:\Users\abc\Documents\workspace\TestBBELMS\bin\deliverables\Standard\6.0.0\TestBBELMS.jad C:\Users\abc\Documents\workspace\TestBBELMS\bin
>   JAR file creation failed with error -1

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 3):

Did you install all 3 keys (csi files)?

Here is how you can verify that your application is signed with the required keys.

1. In Eclipse, click on Window -> Preferences.
2. Expand BlackBerry Java Plug-in and click on Signature Tool.
3. Uncheck "Run SignatureTool in background".
4. Click OK.
5. Right click on your Project and choose BlackBerry -> Sign With Signature Tool.
6. SignatureTool will remain visible and show what keys are required and signed.

Have all the required keys been signed?  If RRT, RBB or RCR are not installed you did not install all 3 CSI files.  Install the rest and/or request a new set of keys if you no longer have your CSI files.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have solved the issue. I actually removed the existing keys (BlackBerry -> Sign -> Remove Existing keys) and re-installed (BlackBerry -> Sign -> Import new keys.) Luckily it worked :)